# Differentiate columns in Recyclerview clicks

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-recyclerview

to begin I would thanks those who help noobi dev like me :p! Let's say that I have a Recyclerview in which every unit element has two images. Actually I am able to find the indice of the unit element clicked to fire the good evenment thanks to this little trick in MyAdapter:

```
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,     parent, false);
    final MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(v);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    return holder;
}
```

Then I start the event this way in the activity:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, countryCollection.getCountryArray(), new CustomItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
            //Launch the events
            ArrayList<String> languageCodeArray = countryCollection.getLanguageCodeArray();
            ArrayList<String> countryIdArray = countryCollection.getCountryIdArray();
            if(position >0){
                String languageCode = languageCodeArray.get(position-1);
                String countryId = countryIdArray.get(position-1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, LetsSpeakActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("country_id", countryId);
                intent.putExtra("language_code", languageCode);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But how can I différentiate the two images of my RecyclerView in order to fire the good event? I've been searching for a while how to differentiate a click on the left or right side of the screen but it is obviously not the right way to do ! Any help would be lovely, I am really stuck...

Comment: please show `MyHolder` class

Comment: Instead  to setOnClickListener for the whole view do setOnClickListener separately for each Image then you will get the ImageView clicked in onClick view parameter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have defined both `ImageView` in your `MyHolder` class, you could set `OnClickListener` on both of them in your holder constructor :

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imageLeft;

    public ImageView imageRight;

    public CustomItemClickListener listenerLeft;

    public CustomItemClickListener listenerRight;

    public MyHolder(View v, CustomItemClickListener listenerLeft, CustomItemClickListener listenerRight) {
        super(v);
        this.listenerLeft = listenerLeft;
        this.listenerRight = listenerRight;
        imageLeft = v.findViewById(R.id.image_left);
        imageRight = v.findViewById(R.id.image_right);

        imageLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listenerLeft.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
            }
        });

        imageRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listenerRight.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

while injecting both listener in `onCreateViewHolder` :

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model, parent, false);
    return new MyHolder(v, mImageLeftListener, mImageRightListener);
}
```

You can introduce both of these listener in your Adapter constructor like you did with `listener`

Or if you want to pass only one listener, you can define your `CustomItemClickListener` interface with 2 methods (or just 1 with an additional param to differentiate the image clicked) :

```
public interface CustomItemClickListener {
    void onLeftImageClick(View view, int position);
    void onRightImageClick(View view, int position);
}
```